# Socket programming - function : bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I have an issue when trying to create a function of the following code so i can reuse it to create new socket easily :

```
if ( (socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ) < 0 ) /* return 1 if okay */
  {
    printf("ERROR opening socket ... 1");
  }

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /*Define the domain used*/
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT); /*Declare port #PORT to be used*/
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("INADDR_ANY"); /*Permit any incoming IP address by declaring INADDR_ANY*/

  setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&tv , sizeof (struct timeval)); 

// Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, SERVER, &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) 
  {
    printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
    return -1;
  }

if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    printf("\nConnection Failed  \n");
    return -1;
 }
else
{
  printf("\n Connected \n");
}
```

The above code is working nice for me, but when i try to create a simple function to regroup this, when i try to send cmd with `sendto()` i have the error `bad file descriptor`.

So here is my function :

```
void open_socket( int s_fd, struct sockaddr_in s_addr, struct timeval tv, char* ID_IP, int ID_Port)
{

    if ( (s_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ) < 0 ) /* return 1 if okay */
      {
        printf("ERROR opening socket ");
      }

      s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /*Define the domain used*/
      s_addr.sin_port = htons(ID_Port); /*Declare port #PORT to be used*/
      s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("INADDR_ANY"); /*Permit any incoming IP address by declaring INADDR_ANY*/

      setsockopt(s_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&tv , sizeof (struct timeval)); /*config du timeout*/

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, ID_IP, &s_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
      {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
      }

    if (connect(s_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof(s_addr)) < 0)
      {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
     }
    else
    {
        printf("Socket Connected\n" );
    }

}
```

and i try to call it with :

```
 //SOCKET 1
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; /* Server Socket address structure*/
  int serv_len=sizeof(serv_addr);
  int socket_fd;

  struct timeval tv;
  tv.tv_sec=1 ; 
  tv.tv_usec=0; 

  //FUNCTION CALL
  open_socket( socket_fd, serv_addr, tv, SERVER, PORT);
```

and the error appears here :

```
 //send the message
        if ( (sendto(socket_fd , cmd_final, BUFFLEN , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, serv_len) ) < 0 )
        {
          perror("ERROR > send cmd failed  : ");
          return 0;
        }
```

I'm pretty sure i'm messing something basic about pointer (i'm a beginner and several years without coding in C) ... I tried a lot of different things but can't find any solution. I would appreciate some help or where to look for !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

The way you're calling `open_socket` doesn't work the way you think. You're passing in `socket_fd` as a parameter, so it won't be updated by the function. You really should be returning the newly created socket as a return value - that way you can handle errors by returning -1 which your calling code can check and act accordingly.

```
int open_socket( struct sockaddr_in s_addr, struct timeval tv, char* ID_IP, int ID_Port)
{
    int s_fd;
    // Code goes here, returning -1 if it fails at any point
    return s_fd;
}
```

And call it like this

```
socket_fd = open_socket(serv_addr, tv, SERVER, PORT);
if(socket_fd==-1)
{
    // Handle failure to create socket
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `open_socket()` is taking `s_fd` *by value*. That is, when the function is called as in:

```
open_socket(socket_fd, serv_addr, tv, SERVER, PORT);
```

The function call above obtains a copy of the `socket_fd` being passed as an argument to the function parameter `s_fd`. Inside the function, this copy is what gets written with the file descriptor obtained by `socket()` and not the variable `socket_fd` that is at the function call.

The C programming language provides you with two mechanisms to get back that file descriptor created inside `open_socket()`:

- Pass the argument *by reference*: the caller has to provide a pointer to the variable which will store the file descriptor:

  ```
  void open_socket(int *s_fd, /* ... */);
  ```
- Return the file descriptor as the *return value* of the function call:

  ```
  int open_socket(/* ... */);
  ```

I suggest you to stick to the latter, since the interface resembles better the one provided by the system call `socket()`. When an error occurs you can simply return `-1` to signal the error, since every file descriptor is non-negative (i.e.: >= 0).

Since you are setting inside `open_socket()` the structure `sockaddr_in` there is no need to pass it through the `s_addr` parameter either.

```
int open_socket(struct timeval tv, const char* ID_IP, int ID_Port)
{
    int s_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in s_addr;

    if ((s_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ) < 0 ) {
        printf("ERROR opening socket ");
        goto err;
    }

    s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /*Define the domain used*/
    s_addr.sin_port = htons(ID_Port); /*Declare port #PORT to be used*/
    s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("INADDR_ANY"); /*Permit any incoming IP address by declaring INADDR_ANY*/

    if (setsockopt(s_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&tv , sizeof (struct timeval))) /*config du timeout*/
        goto err_close_socket;

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, ID_IP, &s_addr.sin_addr) != 1) {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        goto err_close_socket;
    }

    if (connect(s_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof(s_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        goto err_close_socket;
    } 

    printf("Socket Connected\n" );

    return s_fd; // return the socket

err_close_socket:
    close(s_fd);

err:
    return -1; // error
}
```

If an error occurs after a creating the socket (i.e.: after a successful call to `socket()`) the socket has to be *`close()`d* before returning from the function `open_socket()`, otherwise there will be a *resource leak*. This is one of the few situations where it is a good idea to use the `goto` statement: to jump to a common code for error handling.

Comment: I understand my mistake with the `socket_fd`, really clear, thank you !
But, since i want to create multiple socket, i have :
`//SOCK 1
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
  int serv_len=sizeof(serv_addr);
  //SOCK 2
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr_2; 
  int serv_len2=sizeof(serv_addr_2);`
So i think i need to pass `s_addr` as an argument right ? Because i still have a "adress family not supported by protocol" error when correcting the function..
And i did not mention but `char *ID_IP` and int `ID_Port` are constant. replaced by` #define SERVER "192.168.0.10"` & `#define PORT 3000`

Comment: @HacHac you don't need to pass `s_addr` since you are already parameterizing its contents by means of the arguments `SERVER` and `PORT` passed to the `open_socket()`'s parameters `ID_IP` and `ID_Port`, respectively. It works on my system. How are you calling the corrected function?

Comment: i call the function like this `socket_fd_2 = open_socket( tv, IP_2, PORT_2);` this call is working correctly but when i `sendto(socket_fd_2 , cmd_final, BUFFLEN , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr_2, serv_len_2)` i got an error about bad protocol adress. Try lot of different things, arguments .... can't figure it out ...

Comment: @HacHac why are you actually "`connect()`ing" the UDP socket if you are going to use then `sendto()` instead of `send()` ?

Comment: honestly? only because by reading courses and example of UDP communication, I saw that it was necessary to connect() ... but with more practice, maybe i need to `bind()` instead of `connect()`

I just have a computer that need to communicate with 5 equipments in UDP, so i want a way to open_socket() for each thread of each equipment in my main application, if it can help you understand better what i'm doing !

Comment: @HacHac calling `connect()` on an **UDP** socket is for relieving you form having to specify the destination every time. Have you tried with `send()` (instead of `sendto()`) on a socket created by `open_socket()` ?

Comment: you are right, with `send()` it's working ... but I have the impression to fiddle to reach my goals, whereas I think it's relatively simple, but maybe I mix the concepts.
Because if replace `bind` instead of `connect`, i got a bind error.

I have a computer that must send (first) and receive (after orders sent) data of 5 devices (with their own IP, PORT and lots of orders ...) in UDP. Maybe you could give me a simple code example (just prototypes or outlines) if I'm doing things wrong.

Thank you very much for the detailed help, it really helps me to understand!

Comment: The endpoint which is going to send first it's the one that should use `connect()`. Prior to sending, the other endpoint should have performed a `bind()` to the *port* the first endpoint is going to send to. That is, you cannot use that `open_socket()` function for both endpoints.

Comment: So i cannot create like a udpdriver.c and in my main use open_socket(equipment 1) ... open_socket(equipment5) and then sendto(init_cmd,equip_i). And in all my equipement's thread do sendto(cmd,equip_i) then recvfrom(ans_cmd, equip_i) ?

Comment: When you do `sendto(init_cmd,equip_i)`, how do you know which port to use as *destination port* for sending the UDP datagram?

Comment: Sorry i wanted to shorten my previous answer...  what i want to do for each equipment(i) is `sendto(socket_fd_i , cmd_final, BUFFLEN , 0 , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr_i, serv_len_i)`. So i can then received data the same way with `recvfrom( socket_fd_i, recepbuff , BUFFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr_i, &serv_len_i)`. And in order do to things more properly i wanted to create a basic open_socket() function to open each socket of each equipment.

Comment: Either way you have to call `bind()` to a specific well-known port (and the interface as well) on the socket intended to receive first (i.e.: the server). That way that socket is "bound" to that port and the other socket(s) can send to that port. Otherwise which port are the other sockets (i.e.: the clients) going to send to? I would suggest you to write two functions: one for creating the server socket and another for the client sockets.

Comment: I do not have any control over my 5 equipments, i only have their IP and PORT, so i cannot create "client socket". Their IP and PORT's are all different, so i wanted a socket for each equipment.

Comment: *so i cannot create "client socket"* -> Why not? you only need to set up the destination port when `sendto()`ing or `connect()`ing to the port the server socket was bound to with `bind()`.

Comment: (thank you very much for the help, really interesting and really helpful)
So, i do not understand what do you call client/server socket. In my point of view i only have multiple server socket with different IP and PORT associated (multiple `serv_addr_i`). But i'm wrong ?